# How to track the span through different dependencies with Sleuth?

Tags: logging, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth, traceability

I'm learning how to track my distributed processes through all the microservices. I've been playing with Sleuth, Zipkin and different microservices, and it works fantastic! But when I try to do the same in a project interacting between the different dependencies I can not create the same behavior.

This image show how currently is working different microservices.
[image]

This is the diagram of microservices:
[image]

And this image show how works an application with dependencies.
[image]

This is the diagram of application with dependencies:
[image]

I wonder, is it possible to create the same behavior using dependencies as with microservices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the input of @MarcinGrzejszczak as reference, I resolved using a custom span:

```
Span remoteDependency = tracer.nextSpan()
                              .name("dependency_name") 
                              .start();
```

Where `tracer` is an autowired object from `Trace`:

```
@Autowired
private Tracer tracer;
```

Both classes are in `brave` package

```
import brave.Span;
import brave.Tracer;
```

**Result:**

[image: Sample]

If you want to take a look at the implementation in more detail, here is the sample: https://github.com/juanca87/sample-traceability-microservices

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you create a span you can set the service name. Just call `newSpan.remoteServiceName(...)`

Comment: I'm not using a custom span, only default values I mean I've set the property  `spring.application.name` in each service to show their names... I will try to create a Span...

Comment: I did not find a way to make it work with the `remoteServiceName` method, do you have an example?